# Can't boot into Win 10 after installing Kali to seperate partition

Tags: multi-boot, grub, kali-linux

I installed Kali using a live usb on a system with Windows 10 already installed. I used gparted to shrink the windows partition and used the new unallocated space to install kali. In the setup process it did not detect the windows os, and now grub only shows kali. I have tried several tutorials on how to add windows 10 to the grub menu, but every time it says invalid signature when choosing that menu option. The below output shows a EFI partition and a BIOS partition, could that be an issue?

```
root@cozen:/sys/firmware# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 146D170B-D979-4E58-8715-7AE847B58362

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2    923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1159168 869885951 868726784 414.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 975153152 976771071   1617920   790M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 869885952 869887999      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p7 869888000 941840383  71952384  34.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 941840384 975153151  33312768  15.9G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4B8CD7F6-52CE-4095-80CE-E9B5D3730872

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: Yes, the BIOS partition is an issue. It mean you installed Kali in Legacy/CSM mode and Windows is in UEFI mode.

Comment: @MichaelBay what would be the easiest way to fix that?

Comment: Install in UEFI mode? Someone trying to use Kali should know this and a lot more.